# Store in two different folders with multer-storage-cloudinary

Tags: mongodb, express, cloudinary

I would like to store the users' avatars in a folder different than the product's folder in Cloudinary.

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work.
How can I use two different folders in the same project?

Cloudinary configuration:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const multer = require('multer')

 cloudinary.config ({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
})


// PARA ALMACENAR LAS IMAGENES DE LOS PRODUCTOS
 const storage = new CloudinaryStorage ({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params:{
        folder: 'ProductosMarketV2',
        allowedFormats : ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
        // transformation: [{ width: 640, height: 480, crop:'fit'}],
    }
    
});

const parser = multer({storage})


//PARA ALMACENAR LAS IMAGENES DE LOS AVATARES DE USUARIOS
const storage2 = new CloudinaryStorage ({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params:{
        folder: 'ProductosMarketV2/AvataresUsuarios',
        allowedFormats : ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
        // transformation: [{ width: 640, height: 480, crop:'fit'}],
    }
    
});

const parser2 = multer({storage2})

module.exports = {
    cloudinary,
    storage,
    parser,
    parser2
}
```

`parser` works if I use with an avatar or a product and save the images in the correct model in MongoDB. But if I use a`parser2`, it doesn't work.

In my routes, `parser` works and stores the url and filename in mongodb avatar model:

```
router.post('/avatar/:id',
auth,
parser.single('imagesAvatar'),
users.crearAvatar
);
```

with parser2, not works:

```
router.post('/avatar/:id',
auth,
parser2.single('imagesAvatar'),
users.crearAvatar
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you mention it doesn't work, could you share more information about this? Do you get any errors when using parser2, does that part of the code actually get called? Does the image get uploaded always in "ProductosMarketV2" folder even with both parsers?

Comment: It's not works. I have the two configurations, and when i try to use de parser2, no send the image to cloudinary, store, and return the data (url and filename) but if i use parser, works perfectly. I would like to store separately the users' avatar and the products' images......some helps? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send two 2 fields and base on the field name to change the directory:

```
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params: {
        folder: (req, file) => {
            if (file.fieldname === "fieldName1") {
                return 'ProductosMarketV2'
            } else {
                return 'ProductosMarketV2/AvataresUsuarios'
            }
        },
        allowedFormats: ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
        // transformation: [{ width: 640, height: 480, crop:'fit'}],
    }

});

const parser = multer({ storage })
```

And then, when routing, you need to accept both field name:

```
router.put(
    '/editar/:id',
    auth,
    parser.fields([
        {name: 'fieldName1', maxCount: 1},
        {name: 'fieldName2', maxCount: 1}
    ]),
    users.editarUsuario
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I did find the solution:

You can setup your cloudinary data:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const multer = require('multer')


 cloudinary.config ({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
})


// PARA ALMACENAR LAS IMAGENES DE LOS PRODUCTOS
 const storage = new CloudinaryStorage ({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params:{
        folder: 'ProductosMarketV2',
        allowedFormats : ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
        // transformation: [{ width: 640, height: 480, crop:'fit'}],
    }
    
});


//PARA ALMACENAR LAS IMAGENES DE LOS AVATARES DE USUARIOS
const storage2 = new CloudinaryStorage ({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params:{
        folder: 'ProductosMarketV2/AvataresUsuarios',
        allowedFormats : ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
        // transformation: [{ width: 640, height: 480, crop:'fit'}],
    }
    
});

const parser = multer({storage: storage})

//const parser2 = multer({storage2})

module.exports = {
    cloudinary,
    storage,
    storage2,
    parser
}
```

and then in the routes, instead use:

```
const { parser,  storage2} = require ('../cloudinary')
const multer = require('multer')

router.put("/editar/:id", 
    auth, 
    parser.single("imagesAvatar"),//with the folder name in the configuration of cloudinary
    users.editarUsuario
    );

//use multer({storage: 'the folder name')} and allways works
    
router.put("/editar/:id", 
    auth, 
    multer({storage: storage2}).single("imagesAvatar"),
    users.editarUsuario
    );
```

Comment: This does not work with multer-storage-cloudinary 4.0